# get column values by name in django

Tags: python, django

I have this: `Test.objects.all().values('a','b')`

This works, but how can I get values when 'a','b' is string like this:

```
cols='\'a\',\'b\''
```

I have tried eval(cols) but not works...

Comment: do you mean you have a variable `cols='\'a\',\'b\''` and you want to make a statement like `Test.objects.all().values('a','b')` from it?

Comment: yes.. cols is string variable..

Answer (score 0):

```
Test.objects.values(*cols.replace("'", '').split(','))
```